# Spring Boot 2.5 Hibernate error: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

When recent Spring Boot 2.5 release, my project can't call any service method with error:
Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
It works fine with 2.4.x.

SystemConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("qi.ruibu.model");
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", 
    "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.autoReconnect", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.query.substitutions", "true 1, false 0");
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() throws PropertyVetoException {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
```

BaseDaoImpl.java

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Override
@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

private Session getCurrentSession() {
    if (sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() == null) {
        sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

xxxServiceImpl.java

```
Query query = baseDao.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql); // error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day try and search, I finally find the reason:
the package namespace is wrong

beginning of Spring Boot 2.5

@Transactional should use
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

instead of
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please add @Repository @Transactional

Comment: I already add Repository in BaseDaoImpl and Transactional in xxxService